# How to edit values in `Option` by reference

Tags: rust, reference

Given some list of options of big structs:

```
struct big_struct {
    a:i32 // Imagine this is some big datatype
}

let mut tester:Vec<Option<(big_struct,big_struct)>> = vec![
    None,
    Some((big_struct{a:1},big_struct{a:2})),
    None,
];
```

I'm iterating over this list, by another check I know which elements have `Some`, on these elements I want to call a function which edits their values

Example function:

```
fn tester_method(pos:&mut (big_struct,big_struct)) {
    pos.0 = big_struct {a:8};
    pos.1 = big_struct {a:9};
}
```

Function call which doesn't work: `tester_method(&mut tester[1].unwrap());`

How can I do this?

On the function call I get the error:

```
cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<std::option::Option<(big_struct, big_struct)>>`
move occurs because value has type `std::option::Option<(big_struct, big_struct)>`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)
main.rs(132, 24): consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling: `tester_method(tester[1].as_mut().unwrap());` fixes it.

[`.as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html?search=#method.as_mut)